# how can i apply price search between the range like(search between value1-value2) in django admin

Tags: python, django

In my django admin project i have field balance.
and i want to apply search for balance between the range like 2000-5000,5000-7000.....value1-vvalue2,value3-value4..as user wants,  but i do not know how to apply this in my code.i had applied normal search like by name,by city etc... my code is following

**models.py**

```
cust_id=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z\s]+$', message="only characters are allowed")
    cust_first_name=models.CharField(validators=[name_regex],max_length=50)
    cust_middle_name=models.CharField(validators=[name_regex],max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    cust_last_name=models.CharField(validators=[name_regex],max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    father_name=models.CharField(validators=[name_regex],max_length=50)
    village_name=models.CharField(validators=[name_regex],max_length=50)
balance=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=True, null=True)
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from account.models import *
from import_export import resources
from django import forms
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
# from webcam.fields SSSSSSimport CameraField
from django.contrib.admin.options import FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS
from webcam import widgets
from webcam.fields import CameraField
FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS[CameraField] = {'widget': widgets.CameraWidget}

class AccounttResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model=Account
        import_id_fields = ['cust_id']
        # fields=('cust_first_name','balance','village_name')


class AccountAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
# class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
# list_filter = [ValueRangeFilter, ]
    search_fields=['cust_id','cust_first_name','village_name','balance' ]
    resource_class = AccounttResource
    list_display = ['cust_first_name','cust_id']
    list_display_links = ('cust_first_name',)
    readonly_fields=('image_tag_thumb','image_tag','cust_id','balance')


class ReportingResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model=Account
        import_id_fields = ['cust_id']
        fields=('cust_first_name','balance','village_name')

class ReportingAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    # form=AccountPhone
    # fields = ('cust_first_name', 'balance')
    # list_filter = [ValueRangeFilter, ]
    search_fields=['cust_id','cust_first_name','village_name','balance' ]
    resource_class = ReportingResource
    list_display = ['cust_first_name','balance','village_name','total_payment_received']
    list_display_links = ('cust_first_name',)
    readonly_fields=('image_tag_thumb','image_tag','cust_id',)


admin.site.register(Account,AccountAdmin)
admin.site.register(Reporting,ReportingAdmin)
```

now what should i do to apply that range search in my code for balance field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) for more information.

```
class ReportingAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        range = search_term.split('-')
        number1 = None
        number2 = None
        try:
            if len(range>2):
                number1 = int(range[0])
                number1 = int(range[1])
                search_term = ''
        except ValueError:
            pass
        queryset, use_distinct = super(ReportingAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        if number1 and number2:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(balance__gte=number1, balance__lte=number2)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Comment: i dont want values by hard code.these values should entered by user only

Comment: i have run this code but nothing happen.no changes after written this code

Comment: Ah sorry I I misunderstood you, you need to override [get_search_results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results)

Comment: please exlain me in detail i m new in python i dont know how this will be done....thanks

Comment: can you plaese explain me in detail